# What is the red solid line in the "residuals vs leverage" plot produced by `plot.lm()`?

Tags: r, plot, regression, linear-regression, lm

```
fit <- lm(dist ~ speed, cars)
plot(fit, which = 5)
```

[image]

What does the solid red line in the middle of plot mean?

I think it is not about cook's distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the LOESS regression line (with `span = 2/3` and `degree = 2`), by smoothing standardised residuals against leverage.

Internally in `plot.lm()`, variable `xx` is leverage, while `rsp` is Pearson residuals (i.e., standardised residuals). Then, the scattered plot as well as the red solid line is drawn via:

```
graphics::panel.smooth(xx, rsp)
```

Here is what this function does:

```
> panel.smooth
function (x, y, col = par("col"), bg = NA, pch = par("pch"), 
    cex = 1, col.smooth = "red", span = 2/3, iter = 3, ...) 
{
    points(x, y, pch = pch, col = col, bg = bg, cex = cex)
    ok <- is.finite(x) & is.finite(y)
    if (any(ok)) 
        lines(stats::lowess(x[ok], y[ok], f = span, iter = iter), 
            col = col.smooth, ...)
}
<bytecode: 0xabc0004>
<environment: namespace:graphics>
```

---

R documentation for `?plot.lm` does not explain everything. You can at most get the following hint from the "Arguments" section:

```
panel   

    panel function. The useful alternative to `points`, `panel.smooth` can be
    chosen by `add.smooth = TRUE`.

add.smooth  

    logical indicating if a smoother should be added to most plots; see also 
    panel above.
```

Normally `add.smooth = TRUE` is the default, hence you see that solid red line. But you can use `add = FALSE` to suppress it:

```
plot(fit, which = 5, add.smooth = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer!

Comment: I'm sorry to late. I did it right before. Thank you again!.